# Pages wrongly rotated to landscape in the PDF

Tags: graphics, pdf, rotating

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX. In the end, I have a large appendix with pictures of spectra. All pages are supposed to be in portrait format and in my opinion, neither the code nor the pictures indicate the need to rotate single pages to landscape. Still, LaTeX rotates some of them (complete page, not only content), which makes the spectra hard to look at in the PDF.

The pictures I use are EPS files. The pages that are rotated are not random, but only the ones with certain pictures. I created all the pictures in the same way with the same size, so right now I cannot imagine them being different. I compile with Latex and then I convert the DVI to PS and PDF. (I just checked: the DVI seems to have the **correct** orientation of all pages, could this be a problem with PDF creation then?)

Does anyone either a) have an idea what could be wrong with the pictures or what I could change in my existing code to make it stay constantly in portrait format or b) could help me insert code that rotates **the whole page (header, footer, content)** in the PDF?

I added a MWE and a picture of some of the PDF pages I get out. Top and bottom page are *wrongly* in landscape, middle page is correct (portrait).

Thank you for your help!

```
\documentclass[twoside,english,bibliography=totocnumbered,paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,foot=15mm,bmargin=35mm,a4paper} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}%to have a single float on a page at the top
\makeatother

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\lhead{}
\chead[\rightmark]{\rightmark}
\rhead{}
\lfoot[\thepage]{ }
\cfoot{}
\rfoot[]{\thepage}
\section*{Spectra}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Spectra}

\begin{figure*}[h!]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-169_H}\\[0.5cm]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-169_C}\\[0.5cm]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-169_IR}
\end{figure*}

\markright{Spectra}
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-173_H}\\[0.5cm]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-173_C}\\[0.5cm]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-173_Se}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-173_IR}
\end{figure*}
 
\begin{figure*}[h!]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-175_H}\\[0.5cm]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-175_C}\\[0.5cm]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO2-175_Se}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[h!]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO5-409_H}\\[0.5cm]
\includegraphics[height=0.29\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO5-409_C}\\[0.5cm]
\includegraphics[height=0.28\textheight]{../../Spektrenbilder/KRO5-409_IR}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Top and bottom page wrongly in landscape, middle page correctly in portrait.]

Comment: ghostscript sometimes does this. Try with `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!